# Why doesn't youtube have a Download button?

Tags: download, youtube

Youtube has all the buttons viz Upload, Browse, Subscribe, etc. but it doesn't come with an inbuilt 'Download' button. Viewers have to use third party software to download the videos from Youtube. I wonder why.

Comment: Clearly, they do not want (to make it easy for) users to download videos.

Comment: A "Download" button could be very easily implemented, but it probably doesn't fit into their business plan. Have you checked to see if they have a FAQ that answers this question? Have you asked them yourself?

Comment: this would probably be more suited to the webapps site. :D http://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=youtube+download

Answer (score 2):

YouTube doesn't want people to download the video's.. and it may be illegal to do so anyway. They want you to watch it on there site.

Comment: IMHO, they could keep the Download button visible for non-copyrighted videos.

Comment: Besides, their income comes from advertising. Downloadable videos means less pages views and add clicks. (I'm not being judgmental at all, Google model is amazing and I'm more than happy to click some adds so that youtube can be free).

Comment: Why would they make something that's not in there interest?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense from an advertising perspective though would it, which Google is all about - they want you to watch a stream so they can inject adverts!

Comment: YouTube is owned by Google so I don't think they profit from clicks... the only think you do is putting a charge on the advertisers...

Comment: Still, if people don't click enough times, advertisers will not pay for adds. Internet campaigns are about: results, results and results. How Google actually charges advertisers is irrelevant.